# R: subtraction of elements of a matrix from the elements of another matrix

Tags: r, matrix, equation-solving

I am trying to apply an equation to two matrices. Since I am a beginner R user, it seems very difficult to me. I would be greatful if you could give me some advice.

I have two similarity matrices:

```
> r
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    4    2    2    5    5
[2,]    4    0    8    3    3    2
[3,]    2    8    0    4    4    3
[4,]    2    3    4    0    0    3
[5,]    5    3    4    0    0    5
[6,]    5    2    3    3    5    0

> nr
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    4    7    2    4    3
[2,]    4    0    5    2    3    2
[3,]    7    5    0    3    2    2
[4,]    2    2    3    0    7    2
[5,]    4    3    2    7    0    5
[6,]    3    2    2    2    5    0
```

And I wolud like to apply to these the following:

```
sum((r[i,j]-nr[i,j])^2)/6
```

My great problem is to extract elements of `nr` from the elements `r`.
If I substitute `nr[i,j]` with a number, for example `0.4` then the following works perfectly:

```
s<-numeric()
for (i in 1:nrow(r))
{
  for (j in 1:ncol(r))
{
    s[k]<-sum((r[i,j]-0.4)^2)/6
}
}
> s
[1] 0.02666667
```

But I can't figure out how could I modify this code to solve the original problem. 
I would appreciate any kind of help/suggestion. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simply `sum((r-nr)^2)/6`?

Comment: No, I haven't. I didn't think it could be this simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

normal operators like `+`, `-`, `*`,  `/` and `^` do element wise operations. So simply `(r - nr)^2/6` will do the trick for you.

```
r
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    2    2    2
## [2,]    2    2    2
## [3,]    2    2    2

nr
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    3    3    3
## [2,]    3    3    3
## [3,]    3    3    3


r * nr
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    6    6    6
## [2,]    6    6    6
## [3,]    6    6    6


r - nr
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   -1   -1   -1
## [2,]   -1   -1   -1
## [3,]   -1   -1   -1


(r - nr)^2/6
##           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
## [1,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
## [2,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
## [3,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Comment: I had no idea, thet these operators can be applied to matrices as well. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

For matrix addition or subtraction you can write like this.

A + B, A-B

```
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3

B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2
```

But, in case of multiplication if you write A* B this will give wrong ans.

```
A*B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    6    6
[2,]    6    6    6
[3,]    6    6    6
```

because matrix multiplication process is not like this. It only multiplies it's respective rows and columns values.

The correct answer for matrix multiplication will be.

```
A %*% B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   18   18   18
[2,]   18   18   18
[3,]   18   18   18
```